# Image only appears when selected on canvas Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to add image on canvas with fabric JS , but the image only appears when clicked or selected its surrounding area which is group object.
The image is supposed to show up immediately when the page finish loading. 
Here is the snippet for the source code. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const text = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 10,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});

const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(group);

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function (img) {

    canvas.add(img.set({
          left: group.left + 20,
          top: group.top,
          perPixelTargetFind: true,
          padding: 0,
          hasBorders: false,
          hasControls: false,
          width: 16,
          height: 16,
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'center',
      }));

    img.on('click', function () {
        console.log('img clicked');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Comment: What you want to acheive?

Comment: The image does not show up until i click on the canvas, also the click event attached to the image does not work by showing to the console the text'im clicked'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const text = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 10,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});

const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(group);

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function (img) {

    canvas.add(img.set({
          left: group.left + 20,
          top: group.top,
          perPixelTargetFind: true,
          padding: 0,
          hasBorders: false,
          hasControls: false,
          width: 16,
          height: 16,
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'center',
      }));

/* will not work - use mousedown or you should use events provided by fabric
    img.on('click', function () {
        console.log('img clicked');
    });
*/
// use this option if you want to load image from other domain
}, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});

const mouseDownHandler = (e) => {
console.log('mouseDownHandler: yep! someone clicked on canvas');
if(e.target && e .target.type === "image") console.log('mouseDownHandler: and smashed image!');
}

const selectionCreatedHandler = (e) => {
if(e.target && e .target.type === "image") console.log('selectionCreatedHandler: yep! someone selected image')
}

const selectionUpdatedHandler = (e) => {
if(e.target && e .target.type === "image") console.log('selectionUpdatedHandler: yep! someone selected object instead of previously selected')
}


canvas.on('selection:created', selectionCreatedHandler);
canvas.on('selection:updated', selectionUpdatedHandler);
canvas.on('mouse:down', mouseDownHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mousedown` event not `click`. And use `crossOrigin` property for image object, if you are loading from another server.

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const text = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
  left: circle.left,
  top: circle.top,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 10,
  fill: 'black',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
});

const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
  left: circle.left,
  top: circle.top,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(group);

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function(img) {
  img.set({
    left: group.left + 20,
    top: group.top,
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
    padding: 0,
    hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
  })
  canvas.add(img);
  
  img.on('mousedown', function() {
    console.log('img clicked');
  });

}, {
  crossOrigin: 'annonymous'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am loading the image in my project folder under the root , this is the url '../Content/assets/img/next.png'. I don't know if setting the crossiOrigin is necessary.

Comment: The problem of the image not showing after the canvas is loaded is now fixed,  i have to add canvas.renderAll() after canvas.add(img). Thanks mate

Comment: @Xris `renderAll` is calling inside add method, you no need to call again, if you still want use `requestRenderAll`

Comment: when i do canvas.requestRenderAll(); i get error that requestRenderAll is not function